# Selenium -python element not clickable

Tags: python, facebook, selenium

I am trying to browse facebook via selenium in python.
Here is my script so far.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

usr = ""# I have put 3 different accounts and tested it. Same error
pwd = ""

driver = webdriver.Chrome('E:\python_libs\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")

assert "Facebook" in driver.title

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
elem.send_keys(usr)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
elem.send_keys(pwd)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)



elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".input.textInput")
elem.send_keys("Posted using Python's Selenium WebDriver bindings!")



elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".selected")

elem.click()
time.sleep(5)




driver.close()
```

This script when run on windows with chromedriver obtained and correctly installed returns an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Home\Desktop\facebook_post.py", line 28, in <module>
elem.click()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.42.0-           py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 60, in click
self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.42.0-    py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 370, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.42.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 172, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.42.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: u'unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (481,     185). Other element would receive the click: <input type="file" class="_n _5f0v" title="Choose a file to upload" accept="image/*" name="file" id="js_0">\n  (Session info: chrome=35.0.1916.114)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.1     x86)'
```

I am unable to make head or tail of this.
Any help would be appreciated.

The Graph API is not feasible here as I want to browse as myself and not as some application.
If however browsing as myself can be done by graph API or some other means, please do tell.

Comment: works in firefox. But why does it not work in chrome? I was simply interested to know the reason for this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're doing this process several times, Selenium has some options in WebDriverWait to not waste too much time and check to see if elements are visible.

[Here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html) is the documentation on Waits in Selenium and 
[this](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) is a section of the Python documentation of Selenium that talks about the Expected Conditions classes. It seems that "clickable" is one conditions that you can check for.

In my case, I wrote a simple function that took care of visibility and clicking and called it every time I needed to click on something dynamic.

My example code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

Browser = webdriver.Chrome()

def wait_until_visible_then_click(element):
    element = WebDriverWait(Browser,5,poll_frequency=.2).until(
        EC.visibility_of(element))
    element.click()
```

**EDIT:**

The links above seem to be nerfed. [This](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) is the new documentation on waits and [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) are the expected conditions docs.

Comment: NameError: global name 'Browser' is not defined